# JRuby equivalent of Java Code

Tags: java, jruby

How could I express this java code in JRuby:

```
           // Convert the store to a certificate chain
            CertStore store = response.getCertStore();
            Collection<? extends Certificate> certs = store
                    .getCertificates(null);
            Certificate[] chain = new Certificate[certs.size()];

            int i = 0;
            for (Certificate certificate : certs) {
                chain[i++] = certificate;
            }
```

I have the "store" within JRuby and its recognised as a collection.

e.g.

```
puts store.type 
#Collection
```

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: I,ve tried puts store.get_certificates(/Safe/) but I get the following Type Error: TypeError: can't convert Java::SunSecurityX509::X509CertImpl into String

Answer (score 0):

OK so the problem here is that I was passing in a regular expression and not a CertSelector object.

This code now works as expected.

```
store.get_certificates(nil)
```

Comment: I' suggest you put the the whole code and then accept your answer.